# Empty div with background on Wordpress overlaps ONLY the posts, renders blog useless

Tags: jquery, wordpress, html, parallax, parallax.js

I'm trying to setup a blog for our company and decided to go the Wordpress way. I Set out to completely alter a standard theme so that it could encompass everything we wanted. The blog can be found here http://limsomniacs.limsomnium.com it has only the begining post, nothing fancy yet.

Thing is I wanted to use parallax.js to create a depth field effect using ink splatters so I started out with a far away blurry image of colourful ink splatters.

To my surprise when I added a div inside the wrap div for wordpress it's like it's overlapping just the content div, meaning it does not allow anyone to select text or press the more button and expand the post to its full length...

Parallax.js demands the use of position:fixed and thus i Tried to see if that was the problem but it remains.

Z-index properties using css are completely useless too...

I haven't even started to mess around with the actual .js since anywhere I insert the

```
<div id="paralelo1"></div>
```

it simply overcomes and overlaps all the content div...

Can anybody help me out? Maybe you've seen it happen before, would really appreciate the help.

Thanks in Advance

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to div `#c2`, otherwise the `z-index: 200;` has no effect.

- [Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Adding_z-index)

Comment: Dude you're currently my hero... So simple... So easy... So magical... You Rock!

Comment: @LIMsomnium sure thing glad to help. now you know